# Could this pass as a secured lock file?

Tags: php, session, pbo

I made a lock file to see whether people are logged in on certain pages and I was curious as to if it is actually secure enough to put live or if people can easily bypass this lock.

Here is my code currently:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ((isset($_POST['user'])) && (isset($_POST['pass']))) {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
}
include("config.php");
if ((isset($_SESSION['user']) && (isset($_SESSION['pass'])))) {
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE user = :name and pass = :pass"; 
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->bindValue(':name', $_SESSION['user']);
$result->bindValue(':pass', $_SESSION['pass']);
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
if ($number_of_rows !== 1){
    echo "ERROR - USER AND PASS DO NOT MATCH";
} else { echo "SUCCESS!"; }
} else { echo "YOU NEVER LOGGED IN!"; }
?>
```

I feel like since it checks the database for a user and password match that there isn't really any way around this but at the same time I'm somewhat new to PHP and don't really know.

Comment: *"Could this pass as a secured lock file?"* - As long as you're using prepared statements/PDO, you should be fine. That's what PDO was made for.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this on top of your code.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user']) && empty($_SESSION['pass']))
{
header("location:your_login_page.php");
exit();
}
```

this code automatically redirect user to login page if they are trying to enter in session or registered member area....

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already did that on line 8 with `if ((isset($_SESSION['user']) && (isset($_SESSION['pass']))))` isn't that essentially the same thing?